# Is it possible to redirect process window and handle it your self?

Tags: c#, windows

Today I wanted to open a program in my program as the XBox GameBar does it with Widgets.

Question: Is it possible to do give a program the window size and get a canvas or so back which I can render in my own program? How the program is executed doesn't matter, but there should be no Window visible for the Windows Window Management System (I don't know if it's called that way ;)) so that the user can't see the icon of the child program in his Taskbar.

Does anyone have some experience with this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem.  Can you show us a fully reproducible example of the code you tried? Please include the current result and the desired result.

Comment: I don't have any. It was just a "Is this even possible" and not "How to archive that". I didn't want to invest a bunch of time in something which turns out at the end to be not possible.

Comment: it is possible if i'm getting you right. but first, we have to make sure i'm getting you right. so, you want your app (window) will become parent of your another app's top level window (main window of the app)
if it's the case, it's possible.
and your child window (which is actually not a child) will not be seen by typing alt-tab etc.
if it's your case, tell me, i'm gonna try to help you

Comment: @BierDav in programming almost anything is possible.  But if you dont want to invest time in trying some code.... how could we ever help you?  it is a policy of stackoverflow to post your code

Comment: @GurhanPolat thanks for your willingness to help. I would be great if you tell me everything you know about that

Comment: @BierDav these two app you want to combine are all yours (you have source code of two of them) or second one is from a different source (you dont have source code)? This question will make the difference. If you have two apps, it would be easy but if not we have to inject dll into the second one, so the answer will be going different for either case

Comment: first: I have the source code, second: I don't have to source code (it may be any random application)

Comment: @BierDav i really wanted to help you but i have no time to do it just because of my works to be done. but i may show you the way; you need to inject a dll which finds the main window of the app and call SetParent win32 api. you need to call SetParent as SetParent(MainWindowHandleOfApp, YourContainerWindowHandle). you will see that the app will become your child windows. i'm gonna do that as a medium story but i'm struggling with my works now.